# Ember.js - First simple tutorial doesnt work

Tags: ember.js

I wrote a first Ember.js Application, but it doesnt work properly.

**My index.html**

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
      {{#if Songs.totalReviews}}
          Read all my {{Songs.totalReviews}} reviews!
      {{else}}
          There are no reviews right now.
      {{/if}}

      {{#each Songs.songsController}}
          <h3>{{title}}</h3>
          <p>{{artist}} - {{genre}}</p>
      {{/each}}
  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

My app.js

```
      Songs = Ember.Application.create({
        mixmaster: 'Andy',
        totalReviews: 1,
        ready: function(){
            alert('Ember sings helloooooooooo!');
        }
      });

      Songs.Song = Ember.Object.extend({
        title: null,
        artist: null,
        genre: null,
        listens: 0
      });

      mySong = Song.create({
        title: 'Son of the Morning',
        artist: 'Oh, Sleeper',
        genre: 'Screamo'
     });

      Songs.songsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
      content: [],
      init: function(){
          // create an instance of the Song model
          var song = Songs.Song.create({
              title: 'Son of the Morning',
              artist: 'Oh, Sleeper',
              genre: 'Screamo'
          });
          this.pushObject(song);
        }
      });
```

But if I open this page I just get

```
 Read all my 1 reviews!
```

What about the array of the songs? Did I structure it the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the following snippet:

```
  mySong = Song.create({
    title: 'Son of the Morning',
    artist: 'Oh, Sleeper',
    genre: 'Screamo'
 });
```

Here `Song` is not defined u shud have used `Songs.Song.create` instead....modify the code & everything works fine, here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EsF4R/99/)

Answer (score 0):

it seem the problem is `{{#each Songs.songsController}}`

should use `{{#each Songs.songsController.content}}`

the problem is solved.